# O Método List<T>.ForEach existe?

Tags: c#, lista, xamarin, foreach, método

Estou tentando implementar o [exemplo desta página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.100).aspx), porem no VS2015 (.NET 4.5) diz que o método `ForEach()` não existe

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<String> names = new List<String>();
        names.Add("Bruce");
        names.Add("Alfred");
        names.Add("Tim");
        names.Add("Richard");

        // Display the contents of the list using the Print method.
        names.ForEach(Print);

        // The following demonstrates the anonymous method feature of C#
        // to display the contents of the list to the console.
        names.ForEach(delegate(String name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        });
    }

    private static void Print(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deixei o método `Print` sem implementação, obviamente o mesmo não faz diferença.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, existe. Não consigo imaginar porque está acontecendo isto. Apesar deste código não seguir os padrões estabelecidos, ele deveria funcionar.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0XW6FN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dT6NM9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ForEach3.cs).

Mas como está usando Xamarin ele pode não estar disponível. A documentação do Xamarin diz que está, mas na [documentação do .NET não diz que faz parte da Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Isso mudou , foi criado o [.NET Standard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113264/101) e agora [o .NET rumou para um ambiente único](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

E o método `Print` está implementado sim.

Comment: Vou tentar descobrir este bug fantasma. Será que tem haver ser um projeto do tipo `Portable Application` Xamarin?

Comment: Certamente é isso.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se é bem o seu caso, mas conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299492/1518921)

Conforme o [fórum da MS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/758f7b98-e3ce-41e5-82a2-109f1df446c2/where-is-listlttgtforeach?forum=winappswithcsharp):

> - **en:**
>
>   List.ForEach has been removed in Metro style apps. While the method seems simple it has a number of potential problems when the list gets mutated by the method passed to ForEach. Instead it is recommended that you simply use a foreach loop.
>
>   Wes Haggard | .NET Framework Team (BCL) | [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/)
> - **pt:**
>
>   List.ForEach foi removido em aplicativos estilo Metro. Enquanto o método parece simples, ele tem **um número de potenciais problemas** quando a lista é modificado pelo método passado para ForEach. Em vez disso, é recomendável que você simplesmente usar um loop foreach.

No entanto, ele faz uma aparição na documentação, na qual nenhum lugar existe a afirmação de que este método não é suportado no *.NET* para *Windows Store apps*. Talvez este seja apenas um descuido por parte da equipe de documentação.

Comment: Deve ser isso, `Console Application` funciona normalmente, já na `Portable Application` não.