# O que é e como funciona o .NET Platform Standard?

Tags: .net, clr, asp.net-core, runtime

Recentemente eu tenho estudado o .NET Core e o ASP.NET Core e uma das mudanças para a versão RC2 que está por vir, pelo que eu sei, é o chamado .NET Platform Standard. Esse padrão está descrito no [documento oficial no GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md).

Lendo o documento oficial eu não entendi muito bem, talvez porque eu nunca tenha estudado sobre PCL (Portable Class Libraries). Pelo que eu entendi a ideia é descrever uma forma de identificar plataformas para as quais o código é compilado.

Eu particularmente achei o documento um pouco confuso. Nem sequer entendi muito bem essa ideia de plataformas e qual problema está sendo resolvido por esse padrão.

Dessa maneira: o que realmente é o .NET Platform Standard? Qual problema ele realmente resolve e de que forma ele resolve? O que são essas diversas plataformas e porque precisamos nos preocupar com elas?

Comment: **Eu acho** que me parece ser o padrão de uso do .NET Framework para cada plataforma ou SDK. Por exemplo os aplicativos universais do Windows 10, suas classes e módulos são quase iguais aos do .NET Framework tradicional do Windows, o do Mono usa os mesmos métodos, classes, nomes, locais, poeiras que há no Windows Desktop só que a diferença é que ele é multi-plataforma. É isso o que eu acho que aparenta ser isso, um padrão para cada FCL (Framework Class Library).

Answer (score 8):

### Plataformas .NET

Quando o .NET Framework foi criado a ideia era ter um framework para desenvolvimento de aplicações desktop no Windows. Podemos falar que o framework em si era composto por três componentes principais:

- O CLR (Commom Language Runtime) - De forma resumida é um "Execution Engine" contendo tudo que é necessário para executar as aplicações .NET compiladas em IL. Quando a aplicação .NET é compilada o compilador não gera diretamente um executável nativo em linguagem de máquina, mas sim, arquivos em uma linguagem intermediária chamada MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language). O CLR inclui o compilador JIT, o mecanismo de coleta de lixo, etc. Ele recebe os arquivos em MSIL, utiliza o JIT para transformar em código nativo e permite a execução da aplicação.
- A BCL (Base Class Library) - É a biblioteca básica de classes incluída com o Framework. Quando o .NET Framework é instalado na máquina toda a BCL é copiada para o GAC (Global Assembly Cache). As aplicações .NET quando dependem de um Assembly básico procuram no GAC e assim tem acesso a versão da BCL instalada com o Framework.
- Software de suporte - O que eu chamo aqui de software de suporte inclui o software responsável por inicializar o CLR, prover a interface com o Sistema Operacional, etc.

Apesar disso funcionar bem no Desktop, com o passar do tempo surgiu a necessidade de se utilizar o .NET em novos ambientes. Isso deu origem a "novas formas de .NET". Alguns exemplos são o Silverlight, os aplicativos do Windows Phone 8 e os aplicativos da Windows Store.

Nesses casos todos o .NET completo era inconveniente. O .NET é muito pesado e, portanto, muito custoso para rodar em um browser ou então em um celular. Além disso, para rodar, por exemplo em celulares era necessário um framework otimizado para evitar, por exemplo, um gasto absurdo de bateria.

Cada um desses novos ambientes fez com que, a partir do .NET original, se criasse um "framework especializado". Cada framework especializado possuía seu próprio runtime, sua própria biblioteca básica de classes e seu próprio software de suporte.

A biblioteca básica de cada uma dessas plataformas incluía aquilo que era considerado o necessário para a plataforma. E muitas vezes algo só faz sentido em uma plataforma: por exemplo as API's do Windows Forms não faz sentido no Silverlight nem no Windows Phone da mesma forma que as API's para interagir com um celular não fazem sentido no Desktop.

Em resumo uma plataforma é constituída por um runtime, uma biblioteca básica e o software de suporte. O código que construímos é executado em cima de uma plataforma específica pelo runtime da mesma.

### O Problema de compilar para várias plataformas

Apesar da estratégia de ter diversos "tipos de .NET", cada qual adequado a um ambiente, ter resolvido o problema de otimizar o framework para cada situação, isso introduz um problema: codificar uma biblioteca de classes que funcione em mais de uma plataforma.

Se escolhermos desenvolver somente em uma plataforma específica (por exemplo o .NET para Windows Desktop), não sofremos com esse problema. Mas se quisermos desenvolver para mais de uma plataforma, podemos precisar compartilhar código. Se desenvolvermos um software que terá uma versão para Windows Desktop, uma versão Silverlight e uma versão Windows Store, podemos acabar precisando desenvolver bibliotecas de classes que precisam ser usadas em mais de uma plataforma.

O problema disso é que uma vez que cada plataforma tem sua própria biblioteca básica, não podemos garantir que as API's que usamos na nossa biblioteca de classes vá funcionar em todas as plataformas.

O PCL (Portable Class Libraries) resolvia esse problema identificando conjuntos de plataformas. Isso significa que desenvolvíamos as bibliotecas de classes para um conjunto fixo de plataformas e sabíamos que teríamos acesso somente as API's disponíveis simultaneamente em todas as plataformas do conjunto.

Apesar dessa abordagem resolver o problema de uma forma, ela introduz outro problema: como o conjunto de plataformas foi "hard-coded", se uma nova plataforma é criada que suporta as API's usadas, a biblioteca não pode ser usada nela.

### Como o .NET Platform Standard resolve o problema?

O .NET Platform Standard é a nova solução proposta para esse problema. A ideia é termos um único TFM (Target Framework Moniker) que identifica um padrão. Esse TFM possui uma versão que identifica um conjunto de API's disponíveis. É algo parecido com o API Level do Android.

A ideia por trás disso é: cada versão do .NET Platform Standard estabelece um contrato. Esses contratos dizem quais API's devem estar disponíveis.

Cada plataforma então "assina o contrato" de uma versão do .NET Platform Standard. Isso significa que a biblioteca básica dessa plataforma apresenta **com certeza no mínimo** as API's daquele contrato, daquela versão do .NET Platform Standard.

Os desenvolvedores de bibliotecas de classes então desenvolvem não para uma plataforma específica, ou conjunto de plataformas, mas para uma versão específica do .NET Platform Standard. É como usar uma interface em código: sabemos que os métodos estarão disponíveis. No caso, ao desenvolver para uma versão específica do .NET Platform Standard temos certeza que as API's daquela versão estão disponíveis.

A vantagem sobre o PCL é exatamente que se uma nova plataforma aparece e dá suporte aquelas API's, basta ela assinar o contrato daquela versão do .NET Platform Standard e o código das bibliotecas construídas para aquela versão irá funciona na nova plataforma.

Na prática o TFM do .NET Platform Standard é `netstandardX` sendo X a versão do .NET Platform Standard.

Agora no início houve um "versionamento retroativo" das API's das plataformas principais que existem hoje. Isso significa que a Microsoft já definiu simultaneamente as versões 1.0 até 1.4 do .NET Platform Standard pensando nas API's que as plataformas de hoje disponibilizam.

As API's da versão 1.0 foram escolhidas com base nas plataformas que disponibilizam menos API's hoje, enquanto que a versão 1.4 é a versão com todas as API's.

O [documento oficial](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) mostra como esse versionamento retroativo funciona, com uma tabela que permite mapear as versões do .NET Platform Standard para as plataformas concretas. Basta olhar na tabela para ver, por exemplo, que ao desenvolver para o .NET Platform Standard 1.3 a biblioteca vai funcionar, por exemplo, no .NET Framework 4.6 e no Universal Windows Platform 10.

Conforme novas plataformas precisam de novas API's as versões do .NET Platform vão acabar evoluindo. Cada versão nova inclui todas as API's das versões anteriores e as novas API's que foram escolhidas para a versão.

Em resumo, ao desenvolver para uma versão do .NET Platform Standard e não para uma plataforma específica temos a disponibilidade garantida das API's daquela versão nas plataformas que dão suporte para a mesma. Isso permite as bibliotecas de classes que criamos funcionarem em todas as plataformas atuais que suportam aquela versão do .NET Platform Standard assim como funcionar em todas as novas plataformas que deem suporte a essa versão.

Comment: Parece que andaram mudando as coisas https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-standard/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397

Comment: Lembrando que o mais atualizado é o .net core