# O que devo entender quando dizem ".NET"?

Tags: c#, .net, terminologia

Estou começando a aprender C#. Já entendo o que é o *runtime* e o que é CLI, mas vira e mexe citam .NET como se fosse algo que eu já deveria saber, mas fico sem entender.

Dizer apenas .NET é o mesmo que falar de toda infraestrutura? Ou é algo mais complexo?

Tem hora que o termo parece ser uma coisa, em outro lugar parece que estão falando de outra coisa relacionada, mas diferente.

Comment: Eu considero a pergunta pertinente ao site e estava até razoavelmente formulada. Melhorei um pouco. Não sei se precisa discuti-la no meta, mas não entendi porque os votos de fechamento e os negativos.

Comment: Obrigado pela força Bigown :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é e como funciona o .NET Platform Standard?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113264/o-que-%c3%a9-e-como-funciona-o-net-platform-standard)

Comment: Minha pergunta é mais ampla. E a Resposta do bigown era exatamente oq eu buscava.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.NET sozinho **era** usado **informalmente** pra designar tecnologias ligadas à [CLI (Common Language Infrastructure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure). Por causa disto é comum dizermos que o .NET é uma plataforma. Na verdade, a CLI é realmente a plataforma. O .NET é a implementação mais conhecida da CLI (única atualmente mantida).

Hoje existe uma coisa chamada [.NET Standard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113264/101) (que perdeu a relevância em quase todos os projetos) que determina o mínimo que uma implementação do [CLR (Common Language Runtime)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) (leia, dá para entender melhor o seu funcionamento), [BCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)#Base_Class_Library) e demais componentes deve implementar para se conformar com o padrão especificado no CLI. Mas perdeu força e quase não tem importância mais para maioria dos casos.

Inicialmente praticamente só existia o [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), que foi a primeira implementação completa do CLI, do CLR, e todos os padrões vinculados.

Veio também o [.NET Compact Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) que era para usar em dispositivos com recursos mais limitados. Quase não se usa mais já que a diferença entre eles é pequena e onde ele seria usado hoje comporta uma implementação mais completa.

A Microsoft também lançou o [.NET Micro Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) para dispositivos com capacidade mínima. Também pouco usado já que é muito limitado e tem implementação independente. Eu acho tão diferente do padrão que nem deveria ser considerado com alguma compatibilidade, é só inspirado.

<strike>Recentemente</strike> a Microsoft lançou o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) que roda em diversas plataformas, é mais flexível na implantação, tem menos dependências fortes e conta com algumas tecnologias modernizadas que trazem algumas vantagens.

Também existe o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que gera código nativo a partir de códigos CIL. Tudo conformando com o mesmo padrão. Ele foi oficialmente abandonado, ainda que tenha quem tente manter. Mas já não importa mais, tem coisa melhor (em alguns sentidos) no produto principal.

Também tem o [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) que foi feito independentemente e roda em várias plataformas. Ele existe desde o começo embora demorou para ficar estável. Ele como plataforma completa não tem mais suporte oficial.

[Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) é derivado do Mono para rodar no Mac, Android e iOS. Hoje faz parte da família Microsoft e roda no .NET padrão.

Tem outras implementações e outras tecnologias ligadas ao ecossistema .NET. [Pode ver na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Common_Language_Infrastructure).

Essas implementações, em maior ou menor grau, estão disponíveis como código aberto.

[O nome .NET sozinho passou ter um novo significado que é o .NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) e que na versão 5 assume posição no lugar de todas essas outras implementações citadas.

## Linguagens

.NET não é uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101). Nem um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101), ainda que junto ao ecossistema do .NET exista o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101).

[C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) é claramente a principal linguagem do .NET. Ele mesmo é quase todo escrito em C#. Mas como a CLI foi criada para suportar diversas linguagens, outras são usadas também.

[VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) é outra <strike>fortemente suportada</strike>. [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)) tem ganhado força. Há uma implementação do C++ um pouco fora do padrão chamada [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). Já teve um Java, chamado [J#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Sharp). E o [Windows Power Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) roda em cima do .NET também. A Microsoft iniciou suporte ao [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython), projeto ainda ativo e [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronRuby), já abandonado.

Ainda existem tentativas independentes de fazer essas linguagens funcionarem bem no .NET (olha aí estou falando do .NET de forma genérica). [Boo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(programming_language)) e [Nemerle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemerle) são linguagens independentes feitas pensando no .NET, mas não ganharam tração, apesar de interessantes. Tem [JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET) para .NET. [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_(compiler)) tem uma implementação bem razoável. Até [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_Sharp) e [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronLisp) teve (tem [outra tentativa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_Sharp)). Ainda tem [Object Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygene_(programming_language)).

A lista vai longe. Tem uma [lista incompleta na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages). Quase todas tem perto de zero relevância. Já teve até [Clipper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) .NET :D

O .NET provê a infra para essas linguagens, incluindo uma gigantesca biblioteca padrão que se conforma com o CLS e CTS.

> Dizer apenas .NET é o mesmo que falar da .NET Infraestrutura? Ou é algo mais complexo?

Informalmente pode sim. As pessoas costumam entender. Na verdade, costumam falar .NET tanto pra falar do *framework*, como da infraestrutura, do **ecossistema** envolvendo linguagens, bibliotecas, ferramentas e tudo mais, ainda que não seja estritamente correto. O termo .NET pode estar sendo usado como uma cultura, uma comunidade.

Tem até a [.NET Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Foundation) que regula o uso .NET e tudo à sua volta.

Mas sem uma palavra que acompanhe o termo .NET nem sempre sabemos ao certo do que está falando. Se quiser ser preciso, deve usar os termos mais apropriados para cada caso. Eu diria que os casos mais usados estão falando de um desses .NET que citei acima, em outros estão falando do ecossistema. E em alguns da infraestrutura :)

Espero que mostrar todos esses nomes tenha ajudado entender o que realmente é um pouco confuso, e não tenha provocado mais confusão. Pelo menos tem subsídios para pesquisar mais, e fazer mais perguntas com outras dúvidas à cerca do assunto.

Provavelmente vai querer [ler isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).