# Compatibilidade entre .NET Core 2.0 e .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

Estou criando umas bibliotecas de uso geral (DLLs), para reutilizá-las em projetos .Net Core 2.0 e .Net Framework 4.7. Desejo ter projetos .Net Core no Linux e projetos .Net Framework 4.7 para Windows. Uma biblioteca desenvolvida com .Net Core 2.0 pode se utilizada em projetos .Net Framework 4.7 normalmente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que o melhor caminho para você é desenvolver para [.NET Standard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113264/101) (acho que preciso dar uma resposta atualizada lá) 2.0.

Ele é uma especificação que não deixa você usar recursos exclusivos para uma implementação da CLI ([o .NET em termos gerais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184716/101)). Assim tudo o que pode usar estará disponível não importa onde use.

Claro que isto pode ser um pouco limitante e eventualmente alguma parte prefira usar algo que só funciona em uma plataforma.

O 2.0 ficou interessante porque torna boa parte das APIs do .NET compatíveis. Mas tem um porém.

Há críticas que em muitos casos para atender o padrão uma implementação está lançando uma exceção quando chama algo que aquela plataforma não suporte, ou ainda faz nada, ou seja, compila, mas não funciona como o esperado. Não é muita coisa assim, seria bom ler a documentação antes de usar alguma coisa mais avançada. Isto não acontecia até o .NET Standard 1.6.

[Isso também pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156517/101). É possível usar algumas coisas que não estão no padrão mas ainda assim ser possível [manter compatibilidade entre o Core e o Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128446/101).

[image: Target .NET Standard 2.0]

Criando uma biblioteca cujo alvo é o .NET Standard pode usar em qualquer implementação do .NET que atende o padrão. Obviamente que gerando uma DLL para este padrão impede você de usar qualquer coisa que esteja fora dele.

[Leia mais sobre o .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/). Veja o estado do [.NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/). E sobre as [características de cada versão](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/versions).

[image: .NET Standard Library]

Com o advento do .NET 5 tudo isso é diferente.