# FileHelpers .NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

Estou migrando uma aplicação para .NET CORE 2.0 e a aplicação utilizada a biblioteca FileHelpers, entrei no github da biblioteca e constatei que a mesma ainda não foi migrada para o .NET CORE ... Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar esta biblioteca em um projeto .NET CORE 2.0.

Caso não seja, existe alguma biblioteca em .NET CORE que tenha seu funcionamento similar ao FileHelpers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim. Eu mesmo inclui um referencia para a **última versao alpha** bilblioteca num projecto .NET core 2.0 e nem deu warning nenhum. Normalmente quando há problema de incompatibilidade o compilador emite um warning.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso isso nao resulte para si, voce deve incluir a fonte indicada por eles na sua lista de fontes de pacotes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele é compatível porque ele implementa o .NET Standard. Básicamente o .NET Standard permite voce escrever uma biblioteca compatível com qualquer versao da framework que suporte o mesmo standard. O que isto quer dizer é que pacotes que usam a .NET Framework (por exemplo 4.6.x, 4.7.x, ...) puderao ser usadas em .NET core.

Do mesmo modo que bibliotecas escritas na plataforma .NET core serao compativeis com a .NET framework. Claro, desde que implementem a mesma versao do Standard.

[compatibilidade-entre-net-core-2-0-e-net-framework-4-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230655)

[o-que-posso-fazer-no-net-framework-e-no-net-core-não-e-vice-versa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156517)

[o-que-é-e-como-funciona-o-net-platform-standard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113264)

Comment: Sensacional, funcionou perfeitamente pra mim, muito obrigado !!!